# Running Powermock suite with Ant results in ClassCastExceptions

Tags: java, unit-testing, ant, powermock

The test suit is running just fine in eclipse. However, when we try to run the suit with ANT it throws the following error:

```
 Warning: Caught exception attempting to use SAX to load a SAX XMLReader
 Warning: Exception was: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser cannot be cast to org.xml.sax.XMLReader
 Warning: I will print the stack trace then carry on using the default SAX parser
 java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser cannot be cast to org.xml.sax.XMLReader
     at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.loadClass(XMLReaderFactory.java:199)
     at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(XMLReaderFactory.java:150)
     at org.dom4j.io.SAXHelper.createXMLReader(SAXHelper.java:83)
     at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.createXMLReader(SAXReader.java:894)
     at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.getXMLReader(SAXReader.java:715)
     at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:435)
     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
```

We have tried to ignore the classes, as was suggested by many on the web, like so:

```
@PrepareForTest({MessageUtils.class, FacesUtils.class})
@PowerMockIgnore( { "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "org.dom4j.*", "org.xml.sax.*" })
public class FooTests extends PowerMockTestCase {}
```

This did not solve the problem and we started getting this error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.magnus.newpack.dao.common.SessionManager.<clinit>(SessionManager.java:19)
    at com.magnus.newpack.dao.common.DAOBase.getSession(DAOBase.java:174)
    at com.magnus.newpack.dao.common.DAOBase.beginTransaction(DAOBase.java:63)
    at com.magnus.newpack.dao.PackagesDAO.getPackages(PackagesDAO.java:59)
    at com.magnus.newpack.managers.CreateNewUserManager.getPackages(CreateNewUserManager.java:23)
    at com.magnus.webapp.action.admin.createUserPage.clearValues(createUserPage.java:181)
    at com.magnus.webapp.action.admin.createUserPage.<init>(createUserPage.java:130)
    at com.magnus.service.CreateUserServiceClass.<init>(CreateUserServiceClass.java:36)
    at com.magnus.service.CreateUserServiceErrorsTests.testCreateUserNoNameNoFacesContext(CreateUserServiceErrorsTests.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:691)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:883)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1208)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:758)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:613)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:87)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1062)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:974)
    at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1282)
    at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1246)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate dialect class
    at org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.determineDialect(SettingsFactory.java:409)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2006)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1289)
    at com.magnus.newpack.dao.common.SessionManager.<clinit>(SessionManager.java:14)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect cannot be cast to org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect
    at org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:78)
    ... 37 more
```

After playing around with the previous example for awhile it started to seem like we were just pushing the problem off to be picked up by some other code later on. We have also been playing around with how we are loading the jars so that we can possibly resolve any conflicts but we have not had any luck so far.  Any help someone can offer would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem. What worked for me is setting `fork="true"` on junit task.